# I cannot figure out how to get R to recognize the Pander package

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc, pander

I am trying to get a R -> Docx workflow. I used the tutorial given [here](http://www.r-statistics.com/2013/03/write-ms-word-document-using-r-with-as-little-overhead-as-possible/). The commands to setup your R system (which I used from the tutorial) are:

```
install.packages('pander')
library(knitr)
knit2html("example.rmd")
# installing/loading the package:
if(!require(installr)) { install.packages("installr"); require(installr)} #load / install+load installr 
# Installing pandoc
install.pandoc()
FILE <- "example"
system(paste0("pandoc -o ", FILE, ".docx ", FILE, ".md"))
```

The example file from the site (example.rmd) is:

````
Doc header 1
============
```{r set_knitr_chunk_options}
opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE,message=FALSE,results = "asis") # important for making sure the output will be well formatted.
```

```{r load_pander_methods}
require(pander)
replace.print.methods <- function(PKG_name = "pander") {
   PKG_methods <- as.character(methods(PKG_name))
   print_methods <- gsub(PKG_name, "print", PKG_methods)
   for(i in seq_along(PKG_methods)) {
      f <- eval(parse(text=paste(PKG_name,":::", PKG_methods[i], sep = ""))) # the new function to use for print
      assign(print_methods[i], f, ".GlobalEnv")
   }   
}
replace.print.methods()
## The following might work with some tweaks:
## print <- function (x, ...) UseMethod("pander")
```
Some text explaining the analysis we are doing
```{r}
summary(cars)# a summary table
fit <- lm(dist~speed, data = cars)
fit
plot(cars) # a plot
```
````

This creates a doc file as shown below (there is a graph at the end too):

```
Doc header 1
opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, results = "asis")  # important for making sure the output will be well formatted.
## Warning: there is no package called 'pander'
## Error: no function 'pander' is visible
Some text explaining the analysis we are doing speed dist
 Min. : 4.0 Min. : 2
 1st Qu.:12.0 1st Qu.: 26
 Median :15.0 Median : 36
 Mean :15.4 Mean : 43
 3rd Qu.:19.0 3rd Qu.: 56
 Max. :25.0 Max. :120
Call: lm(formula = dist ~ speed, data = cars)
Coefficients: (Intercept) speed
 -17.58 3.93

![generated graph image][1]
```

Now how can I remove the errors in the generated doc file? I would like to resolve the errors if possible.

Answer (score 3):

[pander](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pander/index.html) is not `knitr`.

You will need to install the `pander` package. (i.e. `install.packages('pander')`) just as you installed `knitr`.

Comment: I already have the package installed. Sorry I forgot to mention that. I still have the error.

Comment: Are you sure you have `require(pander)` in the `load_pander_methods` chunk? I can't replicate your issue when this is the case (as per the blog post)

Comment: I am not sure where the load_pander_methods chunk is.

Comment: It is /(should be) in the file you are attempting to `knit` (`"example.rmd"`) .....

Comment: I edited the question to show the example.rmd file. It has the "require(pander)" in it.